# Simplest way to model correlation between two samples?

Tags: probability, correlation, conditional-probability, simulation

I am dealing with a  bivariate sample (~1000 elements, variables $A,B$) whose marginal distributions are known.

Each marginal distribution is assumed to be drawn from a semicontinuous distribution with positive mass at 0 and a two-parameter gamma for strictly positive values.

What is the simplest (in terms of no further assumptions) way to produce samples of $A,B$ which follow the explained distributions in a way they reproduce the observed **spearman** correlation?

Ideally, I would like to draw samples from A and then obtain samples of $B|A$ so that the correlation is kept.

Comment: The Spearman correlation doesn't care what the marginals are.  A simpler formulation of this problem, then, supposes the marginals are Uniform$(0,1)$ variables.  Now see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/168566.